# chartjs-plugin-labels render HTML

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm using the following library https://github.com/emn178/chartjs-plugin-labels to customize label rendering over a PIE chart implemented using [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/)
https://www.logmyflight.net/vendor/Chart.PieceLabel.js/samples/demo/index.html

My pieceLabel option is:

```
{
  pieceLabel: {
    render: function (args) {
      return '$' + args.value;
    },
    arc: true
  }
}
```

The point is what if I want to render HTML like:

```
 {
      pieceLabel: {
        render: function (args) {
          return '<span>' + args.value + '</span>';
        },
        arc: true
      }
    }
```

The result is that I have labels rendered as text like 123
Any ideas!

Comment: Chart.js usually supports custom callback functions that allow you to render HTML manually. The tooltips, for example, only allow strings to be rendered by chart.js, however using the "custom" parameter you can render DOM elements manually. Worth a try.

Comment: I understand about the tooltip but I could t do the pieceLabel one!